# Select cell by right mouse click

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, telerik, radgridview

How to select cell in RadGridView by right mouse click?

The following code doesn't work:

```
private void RadGridView_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // ... getting grid and cell
    if (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        grid.UnselectAll();
        grid.CurrentCellInfo = new GridViewCellInfo(cell);
        cell.IsCurrent = true;
        cell.IsSelected = true;
    }
}
```

It's strange, but selecting row works fine:

```
if (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
{
    grid.UnselectAll();
    row.IsSelected = true;
    row.IsCurrent = true;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you have code that deselects cells that gets called just after the selection ?

Comment: I've checked it (( This only one place where I select/deselect cells.

Comment: .. and if you remove grid.CurrentCellInfo = new GridViewCellInfo(cell); ?

Comment: The same result. Switch IsSelected and IsCurrent - same. Remove IsCurrent - same.

Comment: Have you ever managed to select a cell by the past ? Maybe the cell is selected but you get no feedback ?

Comment: I just need to select cell and show ContextMenu for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
{
    grid.Focus();
    grid.UnselectAll();
    grid.CurrentCellInfo = new GridViewCellInfo(cell);
    grid.SelectedCells.Add(grid.CurrentCellInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try grid.SelectionMode = Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect ?

Comment: SelectionMode = GridViewSelectionUnit.Cell

Answer (score 0):

Use the OriginalSource the get the Cell that was clicked (remember that can also be null) and set the IsSelected value.